# How to form a path from elements of list in python?

Tags: python, list, path

```
directorylist = ['path', 'to', 'directory', 'file.txt']
```

I want final o/p as

```
"/path/to/directory/file.txt"
```

but without using `"/"`

How can i do it?

Comment: See [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).

Comment: but i cant use list as argument of os.path.join, any other method?

Comment: what do you mean `but without using "/"`?

Comment: @PratikPrajapati, I posted an answer. Check it out. In short use [Unpacking argument list](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) (`*`-operator).

Comment: that means i don't want use "/" in code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) with [`*` operator (unpacking argument list)](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
>>> directorylist = ['path', 'to', 'directory', 'file.txt']
>>> import os
>>> os.path.join(*directorylist)
'path/to/directory/file.txt'
>>> os.path.sep + os.path.join(*directorylist)
'/path/to/directory/file.txt'
```

Comment: thanks falsetru, os.path.join(*directorylist) will work for me